# Setter in GoLang

Tags: go

Sorry for the basic question. I am new to GoLang.

I have a custom type named `ProtectedCustomType` and I don't want the variables within that to be `set` directly by the caller, rather want a `Getter` / `Setter` methods to do that

Below is my `ProtectedCustomType`

```
package custom

type ProtectedCustomType struct {
    name string
    age int
    phoneNumber int
}

func SetAge (pct *ProtectedCustomType, age int)  {
    pct.age=age
}
```

And here is my `main` function

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "./custom"
)
var print =fmt.Println

func structCheck2() {
    pct := ProtectedCustomType{}
    custom.SetAge(pct,23)

    print (pct.Name)
}

func main() {
    //structCheck()
    structCheck2()
}
```

But i couldn't proceed further .. can you please help me on how to achieve getter-setter concept in GoLang ?

Comment: "But i couldn't proceed further" why? What problem did you actually run into? Be specific with your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to have setter you should use method declaration:

```
func(pct *ProtectedCustomType) SetAge (age int)  {
    pct.age = age
}
```

and then you will be able to use:

```
pct.SetAge(23)
```

This kind of declarations enables you to execute function on your structure,
by using

`(pct *ProtectedCustomType)`

Your are passing pointer to your struct so operations on it changes its internal 
representation.

You can read more about this kind of function under [this link](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/methods-on-structs.html), or
under [official documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

Comment: I haven't seen a function defined this type .. what is this called ? i generally know that a function will be of this type `func <name> (<parameter>) <return_type> {//define}` . But what is this type of function is called as ?