# Getter in GoLang

Tags: go

I have a custom type named `ProtectedCustomType` and I don't want the variables within that to be `set` or `get` directly by the caller, rather want a `Getter / Setter` methods to do that.

Below is my `ProtectedCustomType`

```
package custom
import "fmt"

type ProtectedCustomType struct {
    name string
    age string
    phoneNumber int
}



func (pct *ProtectedCustomType) SetAge (age string)   {
    pct.age=age
    fmt.Println(pct.age)
} 

func (pct *ProtectedCustomType) GetAge ()  string  {
    return pct.age
}
```

And here is my main function

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./custom"
)

var print =fmt.Println
func structCheck2() {
    pct := custom.ProtectedCustomType{}
    pct.SetAge("23")
    age:=pct.GetAge
    print (age)
}

func main() {
    structCheck2()
}
```

I am expecting it to print `23`, but it is printing as `0x48b950`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setter in GoLang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931254/setter-in-golang)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (your code) takes the `pct` instance's `GetAge` method and stores it in a variable:

```
age:=pct.GetAge
```

This calls the `GetAge` method and stores its return value in a variable:

```
age:=pct.GetAge()
```

Consider taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) and reading the [Go Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) to get a basic understanding of Go syntax.